# Displaying html tags as simple string

Tags: php, html

I'd like to make html no interpreted. so when i do an "ECHO" within my php page

the html balise will not be interpreted

for example :

"‹b    ›chat  ‹/b›" will be "   ‹b ›chat  ‹/b›" : true

"‹b    ›chat  ‹/b›" will be **chat** : false

Comment: This is what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: try `echo '‹b ›chat ‹/b›'` with single quotes to not interpret the html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Try this,

```
echo htmlentities("<b>chat</b>");
```